# Different UI for same version of YouTube official iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube

I have the same version (10.22.11614) of the official YouTube app in my iPhone 6 and iPhone 5, but the UI is not same in both of my phones.

My iPhone 5 has the new material design and my iPhone 6 has the old UI.

Why for the same version I'm having two different UIs?

**iPhone  5**

[image: iPhone 5]

**iPhone 6**

[image: iPhone 6]

Comment: Must be something to do with iPhone 5. I have a iPhone 5s and I get the non material design UI only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/05/14/youtube-material-design-test/) Google is testing the Material Design YouTube app.

One of my phone is part it the other one is not.